# Microsoft SQL Server query optimized different based on select distinct vs select count

Tags: sql-server, select, left-join, sql-server-2014

I have a complex query with many left outer joins.

If I take that query

```
select distinct top X [table1].[column1] 
from ....
```

with a couple tables with filters, and look at the query plan its drastically different compared to:

```
select count(distinct [table1].column1) 
from ....
```

What I notice is all the left joins in my statement that are not needed for the filters in the where clause or in the select clause are removed by the optimizer for the select distinct top but are not for the select count statement.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 as my engine.

I am wondering how the select distinct is removing the joins and is that a query hint that I could provide for my select count.

The select distinct performs extremely better than the select count for obvious reasons and I would like my select count to perform as well.

Thanks

Comment: Add your SQL Query

Comment: Get the execution plans, post them to http://pastetheplan.com and then post the links here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `left join`s but no `where` clause, then all the rows in the first table remain in the result set.  They might get repeated, depending on what happens with the joins, but the number of *distinct* values is the same as:

```
select count(distinct [table1].column1)
from table1;
```

This could be generalized to include a `where` clause and joins needed for that, I suppose.

In theory, this would be the same without the `count()` as well . . . assuming that all columns are from the first table:

```
select distinct [table1].column1
from table1;
```

I am surprised that SQL Server recognizes this optimization at all.  I guess it is a good thing that it recognizes it for `count(distinct)` even if not in the other circumstance.